# ReportViewer - Failed to export data

Tags: .net, timeout, export, reportviewer

I use ReportViewer control (ReportViewer version: 2010 SP1) with LocalReport option (using .rdlc files) to display reports in my project. When export data in ReportViewer control to Excel file, I got the **"The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD"** error message. The data contained in the ReportViewer control is quite large - more than 25.000 records, each record has 23 columns.

The duration from the time I clicked on the Excel export link to the time I got the IE error page is 10 minutes. I repeated the test multiple times and the results are the same. So I suspected this might be caused by a timeout configuration of the web application. Thus, I set the httpRuntime/executionTimeout (obviously I set the debug mode of the web to false), session timeout, and form authentication cookie timeout to 1 hour, but the result is the same (got the error page after 10 minutes).

Do you know what caused this issue? Could you please help?

Below is the details of the error I got.

**Exception information:**

> Exception type: HttpException 
>   
>     Exception message: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
>   
>     at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
>   
>     at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
>   
>     at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
>   
>     at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   
>     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation.StreamToResponse(Stream data, HttpResponse response)
>   
>     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response)
>   
>     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>   
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

**Request information:**

> Request URL: http://example.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Culture=2057&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=2057&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=44d295a585a8483984f0f7606a3d7fa5&Mode=true&OpType=Export&FileName=Invoice_&_Order_List_Report_20130801032657&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=Excel
>   
> Request path: /app_virtual_dir/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd 
>   
> User host address: xxx
>   
> User: xxx
>   
> Is authenticated: True 
>   
> Authentication Type: Forms 
>   
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx

Comment: How do you fill your dataset?

Comment: I use EntityFramework to get data from database into my POCO classes. The data source is a list of POCO objects. The report is displayed well so I don't think the issue is from the datasource/dataset. The issue only occurs when I export the report.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?